# Search.twitter.com Atom Feed doesn't work (?)

Tags: twitter, joomla, rss, feed, atom-feed

I'm using the Joomla 1.5 Feed module to display Tweets on my website. Now it suddenly doesn't work anymore (it was still working yesterday). Is anyone aware of any changes Twitter made in their syntax or anything? I'm using the following line to get the tweets: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=from%3AUsername

Answer (score 2):

This API has [now been retired](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates):

> Requests to search.twitter.com/search.* will receive HTTP 410 Gone. Use GET search/tweets instead.

note also that:

> JSON is API v1.1's only output format. XML, RSS, and ATOM response formats will be retired along with API v1.

Comment: The new APIs require an authentication code, so this new API isn't a drop-in replacement.